# Python ctypes MemoryError in fcgi process from PIL library

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, fastcgi

I'm trying to run Django on shared hosting (Bluehost). I'm using functionality that requires PIL. PIL imports and works from an interactive shell, but in my fcgi process it crashes with a MemoryError at from PIL import image. Any help on why it might be failing inside fcgi would be much appreciated.

```
__Environment Info__:  
Python2.7

Local installs of libjpg, zlib, freetype, and lcms

Virtualenv:  
Django 1.3, PIL, flup, etc.

__Stack Trace__:  

    File ".../feincms_thumbnail.py", line 3, in <module>  
        from PIL import Image

    File ".../PIL/Image.py", line 45, in <module>  
        \__import__("FixTk")

    File ".../python2.7/lib-tk/FixTk.py", line 15, in <module>  
        import ctypes

    File ".../python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 549, in <module>  
        CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)

__.fcgi__:  

<!-- language: python -->
    # setup paths
    # set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in os.environ  

    from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi  
    runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Comment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=781578

Answer (score 25):

I have temporarily fixed that error commenting the last line in this file `$HOME/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py` that is something like `#CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)`.

That worked for me, but I don't know exactly what is the problem.

**UPDATE**

In python 2.7.3 the line number is :279 not the last as I said above.

**UPDATE 2**
Since the line may vary between minor versions, you should look for a chunk of code that looks something like this:

```
# XXX for whatever reasons, creating the first instance of a callback
# function is needed for the unittests on Win64 to succeed.  This MAY
# be a compiler bug, since the problem occurs only when _ctypes is
# compiled with the MS SDK compiler.  Or an uninitialized variable?
CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)
```

Comment: As an alternative approach I had modified Django to use ImageMagick instead of PIL (https://github.com/psidebotham/Django-1.3-ImageMagick-Mod). I'll try to give your approach a try in the next day or two to see if it works for me.

Comment: +1 - Hacky, but works. Has this issue been reported? Very nasty bug, hope someone is working on it.

Comment: is there any other solution for this? hack works, but need to see if there is better way to solve this

Answer (score 3):

try running this command:

```
setsebool -P httpd_tmp_exec on
```

fixes things for me on CentOS. Taken from this post:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=645193

Comment: This would only work, if in your setup, SELinux is enabled. 

In other cases, we'd have to rely on the other answers I guess....

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on eos87's answer a bit, this does fix the problem for me as well, and judging by the comment before that line, it sounds like it was added as a workaround to a windows bug, but the workaround is apparently causing trouble of its own. Here's the bit at the end of `__init__.py`:

```
# XXX for whatever reasons, creating the first instance of a callback
# function is needed for the unittests on Win64 to succeed.  This MAY
# be a compiler bug, since the problem occurs only when _ctypes is
# compiled with the MS SDK compiler.  Or an uninitialized variable?
CFUNCTYPE(c_int)(lambda: None)
```

It looks like it's safe to remove.

FWIW, this issue showed up for me on a Centos 5.7 x64 box when using python 2.6 as installed (in parallel with python 2.4) from [epel](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). The file was found here: `/usr/lib64/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py`

Also note that the exception that shows up is a MemoryError which according to `strace` results from a segmentation fault immediately (though perhaps coincidentally) after a call to `munmap`; and it only shows up when running as FastCGI.

Comment: I've solved this a bit differenly - see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=717404